Is there a function $f :A^{<\mathbb{N}}\to E$ such that $f (s{}^\frown a)=h(f(s),a,|s|)$ for any $s\in A^{<\mathbb{N}}$ and $a\in A$?
Given a set $A$, define $A^{<\mathbb{N}}:=\cup _{n\in\mathbb{N}}A^n$ with $A^0:=\{\emptyset\} $ and $A^n$ being the $n$-fold cartesian product of $A$.
For any $s:=(s_0,\cdots,s_{n-1})\in A^n\subseteq A^{<\mathbb{N}}$ and $a\in A$, define $s{}^\frown a$ as the finite sequence $(s_0,\cdots,s_{n-1},a)\in A^{n+1}$. Also define $\emptyset {}^\frown a:=a\in A^1$ for all $a\in A$.
Let $E,A$ be two non-empty sets, $x_0\in E$ and $h:E\times A\times \mathbb{N}\to E$. My question is: is there a function $f :A^{<\mathbb{N}}\to E$ such that $f(\emptyset)=x_0$ and $f (s{}^\frown a)=h(f(s),a,|s|)$ for any $s\in A^{<\mathbb{N}}$ and $a\in A$? Here $|s|$ denotes the length of a sequence $s\in A^{<\mathbb{N}}$.

In the book "Notes on Set Theory" (by Yiannis Moschovakis) I found the following theorems.
String Recursion Theorem: For any two sets $A,E$, each $x_0\in E$, and each function $h:E\times A\to E$, there is exactly one function $f:A^{<\mathbb{N}}\to E$ which satisfies the identities: $f(\emptyset )=e$ and $f(s{}^\frown a)=h(f(s),a)$ for any $s\in A^{<\mathbb{N}}$ and $x_0\in A$.
String Recursion Theorem with Parameters: For any three sets $A,E,Y$, each $a\in E$ and any functions $g:Y\to E$ and $h:E\times A\times Y\to E$, there exists exactly one function $f:A^{<\mathbb{N}}\times Y\to E$ which satisfies the identities: $f(\emptyset ,y)=g(y)$ and $f(s{}^\frown a,y)=h(f(s,y),a,y)$ for any $y\in Y$, $s\in A^{<\mathbb{N}}$ and $a\in A$.
I tried to use the previous theorems to obtain a function $f$ satisfying those equations by a failed.

I'm trying to obtain that version of Recursion Theorem in order to define rigorously some schemes in Descriptive Set Theory (for example, see the question Formalizing the construction of a Cantor scheme).
Generally I'm dealing with functions $h$ having properties such $U=\cup _{a\in A}h(U,a,n)$ with $\text{diam}(h(U,a,n))\leq 2^{-n}$ for any set $U\in E$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

The fastest way would be to show that the $f$ is well-defined that way.
If you want to apply the String Recursion Theorem, you can proceed as follows:
Consider $B=A\times \mathbb{N}$ and define $H(e,(a,n)):=h(e,a,n)$. Then you get a function $g:B^{<\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow E$ such that $g(\emptyset)=x_0$ and $g(s^\frown(a,n))=H(g(s),(a,n))=h(g(s),a,n)$.
Define a map $i: A^{<\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow B^{<\mathbb{N}}$ by the String Recursion Theorem as follows: Take $G:B^{<\mathbb{N}}\times A\rightarrow B^{<\mathbb{N}}; (s,a)\mapsto s^\frown (a,|s|)$ and obtain $i: A^{<\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow B^{<\mathbb{N}}$ with $i(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ and $i(s^\frown a)=G(i(s),a)=i(s)^\frown (a,|i(s)|)$. Note that by induction $s$ and $i(s)$ have the same length: This is true for $s=\emptyset$ and if $|s|=|i(s)|$ then $|s^\frown a|=|s|+1=|i(s)|+1=|i(s)^\frown (a,|i(s)|)|=|i(s^\frown a)|$.
Finally, define $f(s)=g(i(s))$. Then $f(s^\frown a)=g(i(s^\frown a))=g(i(s)^\frown (a,|s|))=h(g(i(s)),a,|s|)=h(f(s),a,|s|)$.

Thank you! I submitted an edit to correct the function $G$ because I think there's a mistake!

Could you please tell me how to show directly that $f$ is well-defined without using the recursion theorem? I don't see how to define $f$ without recursion!

I would look at the proof of the String Recursion Theorem with Parameters and adapt it to show the following slightly different version of it: For any sets $A,E$, each $a\in E$, any $x_0\in E$ and any $h: E×A×\mathbb{N}\rightarrow E$, there exists exactly one function $f:A\rightarrow E$ which satisfies the identities:$ f(\emptyset)=x_0$ and $f(s^\frown a)=h(f(s),a,|s|)$ for any $ s\in A^{<\mathbb{N}}$ and $a\in A$.
The idea is that first define $f$ in the obvious way for $\emptyset$ and then use $h$ for the recursive step once you defined it for all sequences with length less than $n$.

I think there's a mistake in your answer! I just realized that $i(s{}^\frown a)=i(s){}^\frown (a,\color{red}{|i(s)|})$ and not $i(s){}^\frown (a,|s|)$. Do you know how to correct this mistake?

$s$ and $i(s)$ have the same length. This is true for $s=\emptyset$ and if $|s|=|i(s)|$ then $|s^\frown a|=|s|+1=|i(s)|+1=|i(s)^\frown (a,|i(s)|)|=|i(s^\frown a)|$.
